# Find the Closest match in EXCEL based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please find below my problem statement:

Requirement : For every row in the below displayed records, I want to find the records  within 10 minutes range and within +-15 units of the quantity. And then find the record which is closest in time with the current record and fetch the Price value.

Example : Say for the first record with Sno=1,the records which fall within 10 min time range and within +-15 units of quantity are records with Sno = 2,4,6. Of these three records the one closest in time range is record Sno=2.So I want to get the Price value for record with Sno=2 which is 12.

---

- Sno       Price    Quantity              Time
- 1         10        100              05/08/2013 10:12:13 AM
- 2         12        111              05/08/2013 10:10:11 AM
- 3         13        123              05/08/2013 10:22:13 AM
- 4         2         111              05/08/2013 10:22:13 AM
- 5         13        112              05/08/2013 10:42:13 AM
- 6         14        100              05/08/2013 10:15:13 AM

---

Appreciate your help :)

Thanks
RVK

Comment: I tried to find the record which satisfies the time and quantity condition and then find the record with lowest time difference among them using the formula "=SMALL(IF(OR(OR(K1-$K$1:$K$6<=1/144),OR(I1-$I$1:$I$6<15)),K1-$K$1:$K$6),1)" WHERE K1:K6 contain the Time column values and I1:I6 contain the quantity column values. But when i execute this I get ########### displayed in the cell with a comment stating "Dates and Time too large to display or negative"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming data in `A2:D7`, enter in `E2` and fill down:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(ABS(D$2:D$7-D2)<TIME(,10,1))/FREQUENCY(0,ABS(D$2:D$7-D2)*(2*(ABS(C$2:C$7-C2)<=15)-1)-(A$2:A$7=A2)),B$2:B$7)`

**Explanation**

The formula can be broken down into several components (by highlighting the chosen section in the formula bar and pressing F9):

A: `=(ABS(D$2:D$7-D2)<TIME(0,10,1))` returns `{TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE}` which is an array indicating if it is within 10 minutes (or `10:01` to account for rounding)

B: `=FREQUENCY(0,{...})` returns `{0;1;0;0;0;0;0}` which is the closest match in time within 15 units of quantity. `ABS(D$2:D$7-D2)*(2*(ABS(C$2:C$7-C2)<=15)-1)` returns an array of time differences which are positive if the product is within 15 units and negative otherwise, `-(A$2:A$7=A2)` is added so a negative number is returned for the current row. With zero in the first argument, the frequency function will ignore these negative numbers.

C: =`LOOKUP(2,1/A/B,B$2:B$7)` returns the corresponding match where A and B are both 1 or TRUE. The reciprocal is used as LOOKUP ignores errors, if no match is found LOOKUP will return #N/A.

Comment: Thank you :).I get #NA when i use the above formula. Can you explain me what the formula does

Comment: Seemed to work ok for me with sno,price,quantity,date/time in columns A-D, titles in row 1 and data starting from row 2. I've added some extra details, i'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Thankyou :). It worked for me :)..but if for a record there are two matching TIME values(say if there are 2 or more matching records exactly with the same time,then the corresponding value for the first record which matched the criteria is returned.I would like to know in such a case is it possible to get the record which is closest in quantity.(in case there are 2 records with closest time,then we further need to check to get the record with the closest quatity of those two records).

Comment: Also if I want to add some extra criteria, say I also want to check if the record has the same Sno as well.How to modify the formula?

Comment: For finding the record with the closest quantity when times match you could replace `ABS(D$2:D$7-D2)*` with `(ABS(D$2:D$7-D2)+ABS(C$2:C$7-C2)*1E-100)*`. You could add more conditions by making  negative anything that doesn't match the criteria using the logic in part B but this will become unwieldy and a VBA code approach would probably be more desirable.

Comment: Thank You :)...yea I understand but I need to only use the Excel formulae.