# Selecting data values based on time stamps from 2 data sets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, match, lookup

I am working with two sets of data: One that is simply location data and another that is weather data. Both the location data and the weather data have time stamps and dates associated with them, though the weather data is hourly where-as the location data is a single point in time on a single date. What I am hoping to do is match the location data with the nearest timed weather recording, so that the location will be associated with the numerous variables recorded at that hour from the weather station. My data roughly looks as so:

LOCATION DATA

```
5/16/12   9:16AM     Easting Northing
```

WEATHER DATA

```
5/16/2012  8:00AM   Temperature  Wind  Humidity Radiation etc. etc.
5/16/2012  9:00AM   Temperature  Wind  Humidity Radiation etc. etc.
5/16/2012  10:00AM   Temperature  Wind  Humidity Radiation etc. etc.
```

For this example, the location would match up with the 9:00AM weather data from that date as it is closest to 9:00AM. Also, it must be DATE sensitive as well, so it must choose from 5/16/2012 when there is a range of values from 5/1/2012 to 5/31/2012. The final output for this entry would look like:

5/16/12   9:16AM     Easting Northing Temperature  Wind  Humidity Radiation etc. etc. (with these weather variables being selected from the entry of weather data on 5/16/2012 at 9:00AM).

I know this is a lot of information and perhaps a loaded question, but I have been digging for a while and can't seem to figure it out. The link provided below gets somewhat close, but I'm needing all the values from each row to be lined up.

[Find the Closest match in EXCEL based on multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248623/find-the-closest-match-in-excel-based-on-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

This example could be more easily be done in a database, but if you need to do it in Excel, you would need to find the temperature range boundary for each location data point. Then, you would figure out which boundary point (upper or lower bound) has the lowest absolute difference in time compared to the time of your location data point. Then, that time is the weather data point that you would want.

You can do it in Excel using [Array formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-HA010342564.aspx).

Here's how you'd do the min:

```
   =MIN(IF(Weather_Date_Range<=Location_Data_Point_Date_Range,Weather_Date_Range,999999999999))
```

To do the max, replace MIN with MAX, <= with >= and 999999999999 with 0

Then, you would have two formulas comparing the absolute difference between (the min and the location data point date) and (the max and the location data point date). Whichever has the lowest absolute difference is the closest weather observation to the location data point date.